# Push Adobe Flash Player 9 AND 10 to computers?

Tags: flash, adobe, system-center-essentials

Too many times our office has been hit with spyware crawling in through old versions of plugins, so I'm configuring our System Center Essentials server to push updates of Java and Flash. Java is all set, but with Flash I have a quick question.

I got approval for the Adobe Flash distribution, so I added the "Flash Player Catalog for Microsoft Systems Management Server (SMS) 2003 R2" into my SCE server. Now it shows two updates: Adobe Flash Player 9.0.280.0 and Adobe Flash Player 10.1. I approved the 10.1 update immediately.

My question is, should I also approve the 9 update? On the one hand, I want to update anyone with Flash 9 to the latest version; but on the other hand, I assume 10.1 will "cover up" those people with Flash 9 as well as bring all Flash 10 users to the latest version.

But these are just speculation. What are the facts? Do you always approve the latest updates to Flash 9 and 10, or do you decline all 9 updates and only install 10.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Per Adobe](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/406/kb406791.html), Flash 10+ won't work on some older operating systems (Microsoft Windows 98/ME, Macintosh OSX 10.1-10.3, Red Hat Enterprise Linux 3/4).  Chances are you aren't updating any of these OSes through Systems Center, but if you are leave 9.0.280 available.  Otherwise, you can remove.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks! We have all WinXP systems so I will remove it when I get back to work on Tuesday.